# More efficient way to import from CSV

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to import from a CSV to an object. For ease, we'll say it's a city and I have a CSV like so:

```
Seattle,WA,600,000,Seahawks,Starbucks
```

What is the best way to import that into a class? Right now I import CSV, and do something like the following:

```py
with open(filePath,'rb') as r:
    cityReader = csv.reader(r)
    for row in cityReader:
      cityName = row[0]
      state = row[1]
      population=row[2]
      nflTeam=row[3]
      bigCompany=row[4]
      newCity=city(cityName,state,population,nflTeam,bigCompany)
      addToCityList(newCity)
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way. I feel like you maybe could use pandas for something like this? This just doesn't seem the most efficient way.

Comment: I think the best way might be importing as a dataframe.

Comment: Efficient in what way? Is there a problem?

Answer (score -1):

TRY:-

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/path/to/XXX.csv")
for idx, row in df:
    city_name=row[0]
    state = row[1]
```

Comment: Truthfully that seems equivalent to what I was already doing. Which isn't bad, I'm actually happy I was that close! Thank you!